# How can I increase the cursor speed in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-cursor

How can I increase the cursor speed in terminal?
I have Mac OS X by the way.
It would also be interesting to know it for Linux.

I don't know what I should search for in Google (or what you like).

Comment: @Jon Pickup: Definitely not serverfault... Maybe [superuser](http://www.superuser.com/), though.

Comment: You can use https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Comment: Assuming that you mean the blinking cursor speed in the terminal:
For the El Capitan OS it is much easier to go to the '**System Preferences->Keyboard**' and just adjust '**Key Repeat**' and '**Delay Until Repeat**' scales.

Comment: @BillTheLizard this should be reopened: `software tools commonly used by programmers`

Comment: @Qix The terminal is not primarily a programming tool.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You're joking right? The terminal is the best friend of a test suite programmer. How many programmers do you see using a graphical test suite? Because I have yet to see one that actually knows what they're doing use one. As it stands, the terminal is the single most important software tool for programmers. Anything you can compile with your fancy IDE's can be done on a terminal

Comment: @SonarSoundProgramming I don't think you understand the distinction between tools used by programmers and tools that pretty much *only* programmers use. Read the question. This isn't about programming. It's about increasing the cursor speed on the terminal. It's an OS feature question.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm not going to argue semantics, but those using the terminal are primarily using it for development purposes, save the few souls that just want to grab an apt package, or modify some OS features they don't like/agree with. That being said, I can use an IDE for editing text files if I so felt like it, just like others can run terminal commands if they feel like it. Doesn't mean it's primary purpose isn't development. That is the reason the terminal was invented. To develop and run programs.

Comment: @SonarSoundProgramming You understand that if you're just running a program you're not actually programming, right?

Comment: you can also increase the speed by changing the delay time to short in keyboard settings

Answer (score 206, accepted):

***The original answer suggested using 0 as the value but no longer works as of 2019 / MacOS 10 onwards, it's now updated as 1***

---

If by "cursor speed", you mean the repeat rate when holding down a key -  then have a look here:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090823193018149

To summarize, open up a Terminal window and type the following command:

```bash
defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1
```

More detail from the article:

> Everybody knows that you can get a pretty fast keyboard repeat rate by changing a slider on the Keyboard tab of the Keyboard & Mouse System Preferences panel. But you can make it even faster! In Terminal, run this command:
>
> defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0
>
> Then log out and log in again. The fastest setting obtainable via System Preferences is 2 (lower numbers are faster), so you may also want to try a value of 1 if 0 seems too fast. You can always visit the Keyboard & Mouse System Preferences panel to undo your changes.
>
> You may find that a few applications don't handle extremely fast keyboard input very well, but most will do just fine with it.

**Note: It requires a system restart**

Comment: The link says to run this command in Terminal `defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 0`.  It says that 0 is the fastest setting, and that the fastest setting exposed through the official System Settings is 2.

Comment: This links to an article that requires you to log in or something.. it would be more helpful to have the answer printed here!

Comment: Also don't use the "InitialKeyRepeat" value as quoted in the link, start with 'defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 20'
This feature is controlled by the PressAndHold.app located in '/System/Library/Input Methods/'

Comment: closed - but wanted to add that you have to restart your machine

Comment: Be aware the changes may not take affect until you reboot (in my case) your computer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Maybe because it's OSX 10.11?

Comment: DOING THIS WILL MAKE YOUR VIM MOVEMENT EXTREMELY LAGGY !!!!

Comment: 0 is so fast the cursor practically teleports to the new location. 1 is way more manageable. Thanks.

Comment: on my machine (10.14.2) 0 kills repeat. 1 does work and is indeed faster than the fastest preference setting

Comment: It does need a restart, rather than a relog. Thanks

Comment: it affected typing on Chrome. Made it laggy

Comment: How can I revert this change, it's affecting my cursor behavior badly on different applications in MacOS

Comment: bad answer, I cannot control it and the terminal is lag when typing...

Comment: use 1 ,  0 is too fast and can not control

Comment: Just adding another redundant comment, that most of the people coming here need `1`, and not `0` in the given command!

Comment: This did make the cursor stop moving at all. Now I have to press the arrow buttons a myriad of times to actually move the cursor. It's affecting many apps negatively. Beware!

Answer (score 441):

`System Preferences` => `Keyboard` => increase `Key Repeat Rate`

[image]

Comment: This one lets you do it within the bounds set by Apple.  The Accepted Answer allows you more flexibility.

Comment: I increased the "Key Repeat Rate" and reduced the "Delay Until Repeat", it worked for me in terminal & all the editors also.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me and does not require a restart

Comment: this should be the right answer

Comment: This answer sucks and does not work. Cursor now hangs.