# How to stop the Xcode cursor from blinking?

Tags: xcode, macos

I find the incessant blinking of the `Vertical Bar Cursor` or the `Underline Cursor` in Xcode distracting.

The easy solution is to use a block cursor *and* to make that cursor stop blinking. The former is easy:
(Preferences \ Fonts & Colors \ Cursor drop-down menu). How do I do the latter?

The other options (stopping a vertical or underline cursor from blinking) are a recipe to not be able to spot the location of the cursor on a large monitor. Of course a blinking block cursor would be even more distracting than a blinking vertical/underline cursor.

In Emacs lingo, I'm looking for a way to unset `blink-cursor-mode` and to set `x-stretch-cursor`.

Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490124/704972), [2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7908738)

Comment: Don't use the block cursor?

Comment: @matt I rewrote the question to clarify.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Xcode 12**

Upgrade to Xcode 12! The cursor no longer blinks in Xcode 12.

**Pre Xcode 12**

The Terminal team decided at some point that a blinking cursor is distracting (Preferences \ Profiles \ Text \ Cursor \ Blink cursor).

At the time of this writing (Fall 2020; Xcode version <=11) there is no way to have a non-blinking cursor in Xcode.